# WIX Directory Search Always Fails

Tags: wix, conditional-statements

It seems like no matter what I do, any condition I put in my product in WIX blocks my install from running.  Below I've put some simple code that should check if the program file directory exists and if it does, run the installer.  I get a message saying "Program files folder not found." Indicating the condition returns false.  What am I missing here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="*" Name="SetupProject1" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Toshiba" UpgradeCode="bb557911-769b-4a30-8461-3ad860ddc10e">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

<Property Id="PFFOLDER" >
  <DirectorySearch Id="SystemFolderDriverVersion" Path="[ProgramFilesFolder]">
  </DirectorySearch>
</Property>

<Condition Message="Program files folder not found.">
  <![CDATA[PFFOLDER]]>
</Condition>


    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SetupProject1" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SetupProject1" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
        <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->
            <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
        <!-- </Component> -->
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: Nobody still found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add AssignToProperty="yes" to the DirectorySearch element. Also I don't think you need to wrap the property name in a CDATA block.

Comment: changed to this:
    <Property Id="PFFOLDER" >
      <DirectorySearch Id="SystemFolderDriverVersion" Path="[ProgramFilesFolder]" AssignToProperty="yes">
      </DirectorySearch>
    </Property>

Didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the standard action 'AppSearch' runs before 'LaunchConditions' in both the InstallUISequence and InstallExecuteSequence.

The AppSearch action is what populates your PFFOLDER property (if the directory exists). Then you can run the LaunchConditions action to see if installation should be allowed...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (under Windows 10). But when I run the installer with elevated rights, then it works. Odd that for just checking the existence of a directory the installer needs to be run as an administrator.